# Unable to get data for required query

Tags: c, sqlite

I have inserted data using the following code:

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   
   sqlite3 *db;
   char *err_msg = 0;
   
   int rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
   
   if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
       
       fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
       sqlite3_close(db);
       
       return 1;
   }
   
   char *sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Cars;" 
               "CREATE TABLE Cars(Id INT, Name TEXT, Price INT);" 
               "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(1, 'Audi', 52642);" 
               "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(2, 'Mercedes', 57127);" 
               "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(3, 'Skoda', 9000);" 
               "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(4, 'Volvo', 29000);" 
               "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(5, 'Bentley', 350000);" 
               "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(6, 'Citroen', 21000);" 
               "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(7, 'Hummer', 41400);" 
               "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(8, 'Volkswagen', 21600);";

   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, 0, 0, &err_msg);
   
   if (rc != SQLITE_OK ) {
       
       fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", err_msg);
       
       sqlite3_free(err_msg);        
       sqlite3_close(db);
       
       return 1;
   } 
   
   sqlite3_close(db);
   
   return 0;
}
```

It appears the database has been created. The code compiles without any errors
`gcc -o insert_data insert_data.c -lsqlite3 -std=c99`
and to run  `./insert_data`

On entering  `sqlite3` the following appears:

[image]

I set column mode and headers on but unable to get output for query. There is no output for the command `SELECT * FROM Cars`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget semicolon at the end of the query.

`SELECT * FROM Cars;`

EDIT: You're not opening 'test.db' either. The Sqlite3-CLI has opened/created an in-memory database.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the required output by opening the database and adding a semicolon. I should use `.open test.db` and only then proceed with other commands.
[image]